# How to find the number of times a string occurs in a text file?

Tags: python, string, stdin, sys

I'm trying to count the number of times a string occurs in a file of strings.

```
data=open('xyz.txt')
num=[]
    while 1:
        numrow=[]
        count=0
        x=data.readline()
        if x=='':
            break
        for line in data:
            if line==x:
                count+=1
        numrow.append(x)
        numrow.append(count)
        num.append(numrow)
    print(num)
```

When I try the code above, I keep getting the wrong count. Also, I'm not able to get every string and the number of times it appears. Instead, I get the string in the first line with the wrong count.

Is there a way I can print all the distinct strings along with their corresponding counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter()
with open('xyz.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        result += Counter(line.strip().split())
print(result)
```

Comment: The code seems to work just fine. Thank you. Could you tell me what the data type of the output from Counter is?

Comment: `Counter` type similar to a `dict`

Comment: Hey I have a doubt. Could you explain result += Counter(line.strip().split()) this line? Why did we use line.strip().split() instead of using just 'line'?

Comment: So, I want the number of times a line(sentence)repeats in a file of lines. What can I do in that case?

Comment: Then just use `result += Counter([line])`

Comment: when i do that, it gives me each and every character's count.

Comment: use `result += Counter([line])`

Comment: Please use this for more info...https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('xyz.txt') as f:
    result = Counter(f.read().split())
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the code which might help you ...

```
with open('xyz.txt') as f:
    k=f.read().split()
result={}
for element in k:
    if element not in result:
        result[element]=1
    else:
        result[element]+=1
print(result)
print(max(result)) #find max occurance string
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of experimenting, I came across the following:

```py
file = open("xyz.txt", 'r')
count = 0
inline = []
toFind = input("What should I find? > ")
toFind2 = toFind + '\n'
for line in file.readlines():
    line = line.split(' ')
    if toFind in line:
        count += 1
        inline.append("".join(line))
    if toFind2 in line:
        count += 1
        inline.append("".join(line))

print("This was found: " + str(count) + " times.")
```

This should do the trick. =]